# Mouse partially broken?

Tags: mouse, repair

So, my mouse broke a couple of days ago. It's a Vengeance M60 and it is just awesome. The problem came to life after I had plugged and unplugged the mouse a couple of times. The LED underneath the buttons is still lighting up, but the laser isn't working. So my speculations are that the connections for data in the USB connector have been damaged. I figured I could open up the mouse and desolder the USB cable and replace it, but I can't seem to open the mouse even if I unscrew the two visible torx screws. I guess there are some screws hidden underneath the black pads, but I don't want to risk damage to the mouse.
So if anyone have had any similar problem or know either how to open the mouse or any other cause for my problem, please let me know.

I have tried reinstalling drivers, but the mouse isn't even being recognized by my PC.

Comment: Have you contacted [Corsair Support](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/vengeance-m60-performance-fps-laser-gaming-mouse)? Is it recognized by other computers?

Comment: Nope and nope. I will definitely contact Corsair Support. Thank you!

Comment: Before opening the mouse, I'd suggest trying to connect it to another PC. If it is recognized, this could indicate an issue with the USB port(s) on the PC.

Comment: @CharlieRB Thanks, but I have tried that ;)

Answer (score 0):

#### Sorry, but it's likely not the cable.

This forum is for electronics *design* questions, that said it doesn't sound like any of your theories are correct. It sounds like an electronics problem, not a problem with the cable.

In your mouse, the cable is most likely *not* soldered in anyway as most high-end mice use a connector internally. A broken cable typically manifests as all off (no power, no data), but you are getting power through. If you can check in Device Manager, you might be able to tell if it enumerates on the bus (there will be an unknown USB device listed). In that case, you may just have the wrong drivers, but that is unlikely for something as common as an HID-profile device.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Sadly, it doesn't appear in the Device Manager. :/ And should I move the post?

Comment: You're welcome. There's no where on stack exchange to move it too unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I would not exclude the cable problem. Some mice have D+/D- twisted and Gnd/Vcc twisted separately. I can easily imagine one of them failing. Another possibility is that D+/D- are shorted together. Try - carefully and slowly - bending the wire near the entrance at the mouse end, and check if maybe the laser diode lights up.

Opening the mouse generally means lifting either one (or several) pads. If done with some care - just lifting - you can afterwards just stick them back. I you can muster the courage, surely the cable is plugged to the board - measure between the 4 pins for shorts, and to the other end for open circuits.

Soldering *is* difficult on these wires. You might want to look around for a compatible cable from some other USB device.

Comment: I will take a closer look at the cable. I have already tried bending the cable, but sadly, it didn't work at all.

Comment: It is probably not instantaneous - the laser LED will be controlled by the chip in the mouse, and will probably have a short delay before it's switched on. Possibly won't even switch on if there is no comm with the computer. Don't be too afraid of opening the mouse :-) I've repaired quite a few (No, I don't do this for a living).

Comment: OK, so I have tested the continuity between all pins and everything seems to be fine. The annoying thing is that when I disconnect all elements except for the USB cable and the main board, it still just lights up but I can't seem to interact with the buttons that are mounted on the main board, which leads me to believe that it's a problem with either the  processor or some connections on the board.